# What is wrong in my min method (Binary Search Tree)?

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

This is a binary search tree implementation, I cant figure out why my min method (for finding the minimum element in a tree) is not returning the correct answer, but an arbitrary memory address.
I am creating a tree by this constructor BST(3);, now I run min(), it returns correctly 3, but after inserting 1(insert(1) method), min() returns some hex address.

```
class node{
    public:
    int key;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;
};
class BST{
    node *root;
    public:
    BST(){}
    BST(int a){
        root=new node();
        root->left=NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
        root->parent=NULL;
        root->key=a;
    }
    void insert(int n)
    {
       if(search(n))return;
       node *p=root;
       node *m=new node;
       m->key=n;
       m->left=NULL;
       m->right=NULL;

    while(1)
    {
        if(p->key > n)
        {
            //look left
            if(p->left==NULL)
            {
                p->left=m;
                m->parent=p;
                return;
            }
            else
                p=p->left;



        }
        else
        {
            //look right
            if(p->right==NULL)
            {
                p->right=m;
                m->parent=p;
                return;
            }
            else
                p=p->right;

        }
    }
}
bool search(int n)
{
    node *p=root;
    while(1)
    {
        if(p->key > n)
        {
            //look left
            if(p->left==NULL)
                return false;

            else
                p=p->left;



        }
        else if(p->key==n)return true;
        else
        {
            //look right
            if(p->right==NULL)
                return false;

            else
                p=p->right;

        }
    }

}
int min()
{
    node *p=root;
    if(p->left == NULL)
    return (p->key);
    p=p->left;
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you run into undefined behaviour by not returning on all control paths:

```
int min()
{
    node *p=root;
    if(p->left == NULL)
        return (p->key);
    p=p->left;
    //no return here
}
```

Which means that if `p->left` is not `NULL`, anything can happen. Anything!

It looks like you want a loop there instead:

```
int min()
{
    node *p=root;
    while (p->left != NULL)
        p=p->left;
    return (p->key);
}
```

Comment: thanks did this such a silly mistake...how do i delete dis question?

Comment: @user1343868 check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow) when you'd like to delete your post.

Answer (score 0):

If `p->left != NULL`, you don't return anything.